# How to delete duplicates of certain values in list of lists in a specific column of all sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, column

Let's say I have a list of lists like

```
data={{1,0},{2,1},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,1},{5,0},{6,0},{7,0},{8,1},{8,0},{9,3},{9,2},{9,1},{9,0},{10,0}};
```

with varying length and number of columns. It is sorted by a specific column (here by the first column) with applied descending values in another column (here the second column).

**What I want to get is a list of lists with only the maximum value of the applied values in column 2 for every single value in column 1**
like

```
result={{1,0},{2,1},{3,0},{4,0},{5,1},{6,0},{7,0},{8,1},{9,3},{10,0}}
```

With neither `Extract[]` nor `Select[]` nor `Cases[]`did I had any success so far.

**The code has to be Mathematica 4.3 compatible**, because of why I can't use `SelectCasesBy[]` nor `MaxBy[]`..

Sorry if my question is a duplicate. I couldn't find a working solution on your site for my problem so far.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Comment: `((Merge[Rule @@@ data, Max] // Normal) /. Rule :> List ) == result` gives `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Define a function that takes three arguments, a list of data (`d`) to be processed, a column index (`gatherby`) by which to gather the data  and a column index (`maximalby`) by which to determine the maximal:

```
ClearAll[maximalByGatherBy]
maximalByGatherBy[d_, gatherby_, maximalby_] := 
 Sort[#, #1[[maximalby]] >= #2[[maximalby]] &][[1]] & /@ 
 (Select[d, Function[x, x[[gatherby]] == #]] & /@ Union[d[[All, gatherby]]])
```

Examples:

```
maximalByGatherBy[data, 1, 2]
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 3}, {10, 0}}

```
maximalByGatherBy[data, 2, 1]
```

> {{10, 0}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}}

**Original answer:**

All functions used are available from version 1 onwards:

```
Sort[#, #1[[-1]] >= #2[[-1]] &][[1]] & /@ 
  (Cases[data, {#, _}] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]])
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 3}, {10, 0}}

Or

```
Sort[#, #1[[-1]] >= #2[[-1]] &][[1]] & /@ 
  (Select[data, Function[x, x[[1]] == #]] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]])
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 3}, {10, 0}}

Alternatively, you can use `Ordering` (available in Version 4.1) for sorting:

```
 #[[Ordering[#, -1]]][[1]] & /@ (Cases[data, {#, _}] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]]))
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 3}, {10, 0}}

Comment: Brilliant! One can only be grateful of the new functions. 
`Flatten[MaximalBy[Last] /@ GatherBy[data, First], 1]`

Comment: Thank you @rhemans,  Indeed ... How dependent  on `Gather/ GatherBy` we have become:)

Comment: Yes and how frustrating it is without them in older versions of Mathematica... Can't wait to try the different suggestions on monday! Thank you so much, guys! :)

Comment: @kglr works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @andy, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 10.1 we can define:

```
maximalByQuery[dt_] := 
 KeyValueMap[List] @ Query[GroupBy[First -> Last], Max] @ dt

maximalByQuery[dt_, Reverse] :=
 KeyValueMap[{#2, #1} &] @ Query[KeySort @ GroupBy[#, Last -> First, Max] &] @ dt

maximalByQuery[data]
```

{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 1}, {9, 3}, {10, 0}}

```
maximalByQuery[data, Reverse]
```

{{10, 0}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}}